# How to prevent AdMob ads affecting app screen size and orientation

Tags: android, flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

I have a Flutter app with [Google Mobile Ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)

I have painstakingly made the app work with different screen sizes and orientations. But when I play the ad (rewarded ad in immersive mode), the ad often changes the screen orientation which causes UI overflow errors in the app behind the ad. I have also noticed that the ad changes the screen height from 781dp to 829dp on Pixel 4 emulator. Not sure how is this even possible... This happens in `onUserEarnedReward` callback.

Anyway, is there any way to handle this elegantly? Or is this a bug in mobile ads package?
It is not causing an app to crash, but is annoying having these UI errors.

The problems are visibile by printing `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` from below events:

- `setImmersiveMode` - changes orientation if ad is in different orientation than the app
- `onUserEarnedReward` - changes the screen height dp value!?

See below code from the [package example](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/example):

```
 void _showRewardedAd() {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show rewarded before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _rewardedAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
          print('ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
        _createRewardedAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        _createRewardedAd();
      },
    );

    _rewardedAd!.setImmersiveMode(true);
    _rewardedAd!.show(
        onUserEarnedReward: (AdWithoutView ad, RewardItem reward) {
      print('$ad with reward $RewardItem(${reward.amount}, ${reward.type})');
    });
    _rewardedAd = null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

RewardedInterstitial Ad is not release yet.You can't use
RewardedInterstitial Ad in release mode, use Interstitial Ad instead of
RewardedInterstitial Ad.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code section. I have corrected it. I am not using interstatials, it is the regular rewarded ads..